# ReCaptcha Implementation in Perl

Tags: perl, recaptcha

To implement recaptcha in my website.
One option is google API . But for that i need to signup with domain name to get API key.
Is there any other way we can do it ?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/search?q=captcha

Comment: https://metacpan.org/search?q=recaptcha too

Comment: As http://stackoverflow.com/a/16702302/46235 indicates, you don't need a domain name just a descriptive name for a "global key".  Since Google is 'reCaptcha' now, Google is the only place to get reCaptcha.

Comment: I'm about to implement this, which I just found (along with this question, thanks) - it doesn't require any modules - it's just a CGI script: https://www.lemoda.net/perl/cgi-captcha/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a domain name to sign up, per se.

They have a concept of a "global key" where one single domain key would be used on several domains.  When signing up, select the "Enable this key on all domains (global key)" option, and use a unique identifier (domainkey.abhilasha.com) and this will be fine, you can use the key from any domain in the end.

Answer (score 3):

One way: add this code to your perl file that is called by an html form:
Simplified of course

```
my @field_names=qw(name branch email g-recaptcha-response);
foreach $field_name (@field_names)
   {
      if (defined param("$field_name")) 
          {
              $FIELD{$field_name} = param("$field_name");   
}
}

$captcha=$FIELD{'g-recaptcha-response'};

use LWP::Simple;

$secretKey = "put your key here";
$ip = remote_host;
#Remove # rem to test submitted variables are present
#print "secret= $secretKey";
#print " and response= $captcha";
#print " and remoteip= $ip";


$URL = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip;
$contents = get $URL or die;

# contents variable takes the form of: "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2016-11-21T16:02:41Z", "hostname": "www.mydomain.org.uk" 
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

# Split contents variable by comma:
my ($success, $challenge_time, $hostname) = split /,/, $contents; 

# Split success variable by colon:
my ($success_title, $success_value) = split /:/, $success; 

#strip whitespace:
$success_value =~ s/^\s+//;

if ($success_value eq "true")
    {

        print "it worked";
    }else{
       print "it did not";
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for this example in old-school perl !

Answer (score -3):

If you are just trying to block spam, I prefer the honeypot captcha approach: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/10/honeypot-captcha.aspx

Put an input field on your form that should be left blank, then hide it with CSS (preferably in an external CSS file).  A robot will find it and will put spam in it but humans wont see it.

In your form validation script, check the length of the field, if it contains any characters, do not process the form submission.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question “How do I use *ReCaptcha*”. (Also, recaptcha helps digitizing texts, something that an easily circumvented honeypot-approach does not).